# Why my BGR2GRAY Mat returns a color blue in a basic threshold function? [OPENCV]

Tags: java, android, opencv, threshold

I am new to stackoverflow and I sincerely apologize for my format if I'll be doing it wrong (Please don't hesitate to tell what to fix about this thread).

I am trying to create an Image segmentation from an original picture, It returns a white background and a blue color for the green leaf. I was expecting a black and white pixels from the function and I really don't know if I'm doing it right.

I want to use the BGR2GRAY Mat Object as a marker for the original object, trying to separate the leaf from the background. Here is my code.

```
    // IMAGE SEGMENTATION USING WATERSHED ALGORITHM //
    //Create a Mat Object using originalPicture as is:

    //Create an instance of Mat Object using originalPicture as BGR2GRAY:
    Mat imageSegmentationMat = Imgcodecs.imread(originalFilePathStr, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    //Use basic threshold for imageSegmentationMat:
    Imgproc.threshold(originalPicMat,imageSegmentationMat, 86,255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    //test:
    Bitmap imageSegmentationBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageSegmentationMat.cols(), imageSegmentationMat.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(imageSegmentationMat, imageSegmentationBmp);
    imgView_segmentation.setImageBitmap(imageSegmentationBmp);
```

I was expecting to get a black and white only as what I've seen in the OpenCV tutorials. Can anyone please help me by explaining what is happening? Thank you.

Here is a screenshot my output:
http://imageshack.com/a/img924/8520/qPaMdX.png

UPDATE:
I forgot to tell that I was following [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) tutorial about image segmentation and this line is where I got my problem:

```
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

And I just had to convert it to java (The tutorial is written in phyton which I have zero knowledge of it, though it looks so easy to read) here is mine:

```
Imgproc.threshold(grayscaleMat,testThresholdMat,0,255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV+Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

So to ANSWER my question:
my threshold function lacks THRESH_OTSU which creates the problem.
AND I SHOULD ALSO READ MORE DOCUMENTATION.

I should really thank the people here in stackoverflow who actively help people. I love this place <3

Comment: You don't even need to incomodate openCV to tranform a colorful image into a greyscaled one. A "humble" **ColorMatrix** does the trick perfecly and efficiently.

Comment: Wow, I am actually also new to android development. What you recommended is actually useful. I guess my inability to comprehend image processing is also a factor why I am messing this up. I really appreciate your insight. I wish you could explain further on how to solve my problem(If what I posted is understandable enough for a forum such as this). But again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, noone starts being already learned. I'd say... google for `android colormatrix` and discover how fast and easy is to transform an image color space by simply using a different matrix. Sepia toning, Brightness, Orhochrome, GreyScale, ... you name it.

Comment: OOPS! I meant Orthochrome (2 colors: all black or all white), and more: R,G,B separation, Negative, ... plus, you can combine several of these and get more effects (i.e.: Inverted GreyScale with enhanced brightness/contrast, Red - or any other color - Sepia Toning instead of the classical beige, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag for imread seems to be the wrong one. I think it should be [IMREAD_GRAYSCALE from Imgcodecs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/imgcodecs/Imgcodecs.html#IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) the `BGR2GRAY` is for the function [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#cvtColor)

so it should be

```
Mat imageSegmentationMat = Imgcodecs.imread(originalFilePathStr, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

UPDATE:

You may need to convert it to RGBA before bitmap (bug maybe?)

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(imageSegmentationMat, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
```

Comment: He is also writing an 8 bit single channel image to a 4 bit 4 channel image (`8UC1` to `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`). I am guessing the problem might be here.

Comment: @Zindarod I also thought of that, but the documentation says that it can accept that as an input and doesn't put any limitations with respect to different bit sizes, so I am not really sure of it

Comment: I tried this, though I also think that it is one of the problem. I still got the same result. I think you guys are also right about the bitmap conversion. If you guys can tell me on how can I convert the bitmap as grayscale(Because that's where I see my result, I can't check imageSegmentationMat object itself), or if you can tell me how can I use the blue colored as a mask(if I can, that is) I would really appreciate it. Then I'll check your answer and edit so that I can help others who might run into this problem.

Comment: @Jepoy with the cvtcolor function mentioned in my answer it it possible to convert it to the RGBA. I updated my answer, try it out to see if it works (tmp is a mat of same size)

Comment: @api55 : You are actually correct about IMREAD_GRAYSCALE. Though my problem came from the threshold function itself. I sincerely thank you for helping me. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jepoy If you have a solution, then Post an answer or comment this one so people with similar problems can solve theirs quicker :D

Answer (score 2):

From @api55's answer, I tried both and it's an overkill to do both imread as LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE and CvtColor function. But any of them works. ColorMatrix can also be a good alternative. credits to @ModularSynth.

Both of them works(from @api55's)

```
Mat imageSegmentationMat = Imgcodecs.imread(originalFilePathStr, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

and

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(imageSegmentationMat, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
```